# configure nginx for nodejs and elasticsearch on one server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, elasticsearch

I am using nginx as web/proxy server for my website build using MEAN stack.
So the configuration file for nginx looks like

```
    server {  
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domainname.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

          location /blog {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Node server is running on port 3000 and my blog is running on 2368.This setup is running fine.

Now I have included elasticsearch also in the same aws server which is listening to port 9200.I want to make changes in nginx config.

Can someone please help me with the change to include elasticsearch also.I had already tried to include below code but it is not working

```
server {
    listen 9200;
    server_name www.domainname.com;
    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:9200 http://www.domainname.com:9200/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;

}
}
```

Comment: Did you open port 9200 in the EC2 security group? Did you open port 9200 in the server's firewall (iptables)?

Comment: Yes, I did open ports.But the problem is as Soon as I add the above server section nginx service is not coming up.So there is some other way to configure nginx config file.

Comment: If Nginx is failing to start after you make your changes then you need to look in the error log to see what the issue is.

Comment: log file is giving this error.......bind() to 0.0.0.0:9200 failed (98: Address already in use)